# Visual studio 2013 : Open the website using FTP without caching all files

Tags: asp-classic, ftp, visual-studio-2013

I'm using VS 2013, and need to access the asp files on remote server. The project size is quite big, but I only need to access some of them at the same time.

However, it seems the VS caching all the files, so it took very long time (CMIIW) and also, I tried to click ESC to stop the operation, nevertheless the loading icon appear and never put it to close the operation.

I wonder if there's another way so the VS will probably more look like a FTP client like filezilla that only load the dir and files.

Thank You.

Comment: If you use a code management system, something like GIT or Mercurial you wouldn't need to worry about that.

Comment: I'm not under that condition

Comment: If you use git then you have to ssh to the remote server and pull git each time you save...